# Problem with spring quartz

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to invoke method based on some interval time, here are some beans inside applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="MngtTarget"
  class="com.management.engine.Implementation" 
  abstract="false" lazy-init="true" autowire="default" dependency-check="default">

    <bean id="jobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
      <property name="targetObject" ref="MngtTarget" />
      <property name="targetMethod" value="findItemByPIdEndDate"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">

        <property name="jobDetail" ref="jobDetail" />
        <!-- 10 seconds -->
        <property name="startDelay" value="10000" />
        <!-- repeat every 50 seconds -->
        <property name="repeatInterval" value="20000" />
    </bean>


    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="simpleTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Here is the method I'm trying to invoke :

```
public List<Long> I need findItemByPIdEndDate() throws Exception {

                List<Long> list = null;

                try{
                        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

                        Query query = session.getNamedQuery("endDateChecker");
                        list =  query.list();

                        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
                        {
                                System.out.println(list.get(i));
                        }

                        System.out.println("Total " + list.size());

                }catch (HibernateException e){
                        throw new DataAccessException(e.getMessage());
                }

                return list;
        }
```

Here is the exception message that I get :

```
Invocation of method 'findItemByPIdEndDate' on target class [class com.management.engine.Implementation] failed; nested exception is No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
```

I've spent time googling alot so far also I've tried to modify my method like this :

```
 public List<Long> I need findItemByPIdEndDate() throws Exception {

                    List<Long> list = null;

                    try{
                            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

                            Query query = session.getNamedQuery("endDateChecker");
                            list =  query.list();

                            for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
                            {
                                    System.out.println(list.get(i));
                            }

                            System.out.println("Total " + list.size());
                            session.close();
                    }catch (HibernateException e){
                            throw new DataAccessException(e.getMessage());
                    }

                    return list;
            }
```

And I get different error msg, I get : `Invocation of method 'findItemByPIdEndDate' on target class [class com.management.engine.Implementation] failed; nested exception is could not execute query]` , anyone knows what is this all about, any suggestions ? thank you

Also my queries.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>

<sql-query name="endDateChecker">
<return-scalar column="PId" type="java.lang.Long"/>
      <![CDATA[select
   item_pid as PId
     from
         item
        where
        end_date < trunc(sysdate)]]>      
 </sql-query> 
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Please add your Hibernate configuration

Comment: Just print the *query* object and see if you are getting the expected query `'endDateChecker'`

Comment: Where are you getting your session from? I dont see you injecting the sessionFactory into the Object anywhere...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the second error ("could not execute the query"), I don't know and I'm really wondering what the session looks like.

In deed, AFAIK, the persistent context is not available to Quartz Jobs as nothing take care of establishing a Hibernate Session for them (Quartz runs outside the context of Servlets and the open session in view pattern doesn't apply here). This is why you get the first error ("No hibernate session bound to thread").

One solution for this is described in [AOP – Spring – Hibernate Sessions for background threads / jobs](http://raulraja.com/2009/06/13/aop-spring-hibernate-sessions-for-background-threads-jobs/). In this post, the author shows *how you can use Spring AOP proxies to wire a hibernate interceptor that gives you access to the persistence context and it takes cares of closing and opening the sessions for you*.

Didn't test it myself though, but it should work.

Comment: Thank you m8, this wasn't the solution but it led me to one so it qualifies as the right answer . gr8

Comment: Happy I could help. However, can you elaborate just a bit the "this wasn't the solution" so that I can update this answer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I too was facing the same "**HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread**" exception

```
2012-01-13 13:16:15.005 DEBUG MyQuartzJob Caught an exception 
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:63)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:687)
at com.company.somemodule.dao.hibernate.AbstractHibernateDaoImpl.getSession(AbstractHibernateDaoImpl.java:107)
at com.company.somemodule.dao.hibernate.SomeDataDaoImpl.retrieveSomeData(SomeDataDaoImpl.java:264)
```

and I solved it by following the example [here](http://tech.javayogi.com/blogs/blog4.php/2007/11/09/spring-quartz-hibernate-session-problem).

Relevant code

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager;

import com.company.somemodule.dao.SomeDataDao;
import com.company.somemodule.SomeData;

public class MyQuartzJob extends QuartzJobBean implements Runnable {

  private boolean existingTransaction;
  private JobExecutionContext jobExecCtx;
  private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyQuartzJob.class);
  private SomeDataDao someDataDao; //set by Spring
  private Session session;
  private SessionFactory hibernateSessionFactory; //set by Spring

  protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext ctx) throws JobExecutionException 
    this.jobExecCtx = ctx;
    run();
  }

  private void handleHibernateTransactionIntricacies() {
    session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(hibernateSessionFactory, true);
    existingTransaction = SessionFactoryUtils.isSessionTransactional(session, hibernateSessionFactory);
    if (existingTransaction) {
        logger.debug("Found thread-bound Session for Quartz job");
    } else {
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(hibernateSessionFactory, new SessionHolder(session));
    }
  }


  private void releaseHibernateSessionConditionally() {
    if (existingTransaction) {
        logger.debug("Not closing pre-bound Hibernate Session after TransactionalQuartzTask");
    } else {
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(hibernateSessionFactory);
        SessionFactoryUtils.releaseSession(session, hibernateSessionFactory);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    // ..

    // Do the required to avoid HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread
    handleHibernateTransactionIntricacies();

    // Do the transactional operations
    try {

        // Do DAO related operations ..

    } finally {
        releaseHibernateSessionConditionally();
    }
  }

  public void setHibernateSessionFactory(SessionFactory hibernateSessionFactory) {
    this.hibernateSessionFactory = hibernateSessionFactory;
  }

  public void setSomeDataDao(SomeDataDao someDataDao ) {
    this.someDataDao = someDataDao ;
  }
}
```

Relevant bean configuration inside applicationContext.xml

```
<bean name="myJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">  
  <property name="jobClass" value="com.somecompany.worker.MyQuartzJob" />
  <property name="jobDataAsMap">
    <map>
      <entry key="hibernateSessionFactory" value-ref="sessionFactory" />
      <entry key="someDataDao" value-ref="someDataDao" />
    </map>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's bug spring https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9020
And there's workaround.
Configure session with hibernate.current_session_context_class property with this class:
https://gist.github.com/seykron/4770724